# How to modify a variable inside the loss function in each epoch during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have a custom loss function. In each epoch I would like to either keep or throw away my input matrix randomly:

```
import random
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
def decision(probability):
     return random.random() < probability

def my_throw_loss_in1(y_true, y_pred):
     if decision(probability=0.5):
         keep_mask = tf.ones_like(in1)
         total_loss = backend.mean(backend.square(y_true- y_pred)) * keep_mask
         print('Input1 is kept')
     else:
         throw_mask = tf.zeros_like(in1)
         total_loss =  backend.mean(backend.square(y_true- y_pred)) * throw_mask
         print('Input1 is thrown away')
     return total_loss


model.compile(loss= [ my_throw_loss_in1], 
          optimizer='Adam', 
          metrics=['mae'])

history2 = model.fit([x, y], batch_size=10, epochs=150, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

but this would only set the decision value once and doesn't compile the loss in each epoch. How do I write a loss function that its variable can be modified in each epoch?

Here some thoughts:

1. My first guess is to write a callback to pass an argument to the loss function but I did not succeed so far, basically it is not clear for me when I return a value from a callback then how can I pass that value to the loss function?

OR

2. The other way around would be to write the loss function in a callback but then what do I pass to the callback as argument? and how do I compile a model with a loss function in a callback?

The loss function is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477169/how-to-randomly-set-inputs-to-zero-in-keras-during-training-autoencoder-callbac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your loss function as follows in order for it to be evaluated when `fit(*)` is called:

```py
def my_throw_loss_in1(y_true, y_pred):

  probability = 0.5
  random_uniform = tf.random.uniform(shape=[], minval=0., maxval=1., dtype=tf.float32)
  condition = tf.less(random_uniform, probability)
  mask = tf.cond(condition, lambda: tf.ones_like(y_true), lambda: tf.zeros_like(y_true))

  total_loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(tf.keras.backend.square(y_true - y_pred)* mask) 
  tf.print(mask)
  return total_loss
```

First, a random number is generated and then a condition (random number less than the probability you defined) is created based on this number. Afterwards, you just use `tf.cond` to return `tf.ones_like` if your condition is `True`, otherwise `tf.zeros_like`. Finally, the mask is simply applied to your loss.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I expect every time this function prints the mask (I tried a simple string too) but nothing is ever printed, why is that?

Comment: are you using `tf.print(*)` or `print(*)`

Comment: I use tf.print()

Comment: In Google Colab, I am seeing the mask at every epoch.

Comment: I see... maybe there is a problem with pycharm then.